# a complex case with react-router may better solved with "state based router"

Tags: angular-ui-router, react-router

I'm looking for a better solution for my special menu case.
Here's the case:
Let's say we have 6 pages:

- A
- B
- C

  - C1
  - C2
  - C3

Here's how the menu changed when we go from page:C to page:C1
[image]

**The Design is that C1/2/3 are all submenus, when we access these pages, the menu should display C1/2/3 with a return button.**

Here's the requirements:

- the Menu component should be reusable
- the Menu component should automatic determine to show submenus(C1/2/3) with a return button or just ordinary menus.

> then I wrote a Menu component...

It's usage:

```html
/* Routes */
<Route path="A" ... />
<Route path="B" ... />
<Route path="C" ... />
<Route path="C/:Id">
  <Route path="C1" />
  <Route path="C2" />
  <Route path="C3" />
</Route>

/* Menus */
<Menu {...this.props}>
  <Item path="A">A</Item>
  <Item path="B">B</Item>
  <Item path="C">C</Item>
  <SubMenu path="C/:Id">
    <Item path="C1">C1</Item>
    <Item path="C2">C2</Item>
    <Item path="C3">C3</Item>
  </SubMenu>
<Menu>
```

I use the "path" to match and highlight `Item`, this can be done by using react-router's routes props. But it is not done yet, next I need to add links:

```html
/* Menus */
<Menu {...this.props}>
  <Item path="A">
    <Link to="A">A</Link>
  </Item>
  <Item path="B">
    <Link to="B">B</Link>
  </Item>
  <Item path="C">
    <Link to="C">C</Link>
  </Item>
  <SubMenu path="C/:Id">
    <Item path="C1">
      <XLink to="C/:Id/C1">C1</XLink>
    </Item>
    <Item path="C2">
      <XLink to="C/:Id/C2">C2</XLink>
    </Item>
    <Item path="C3">
      <XLink to="C/:Id/C3">C3</XLink>
    </Item>
  </SubMenu>
<Menu>
```

Because path "C/:Id" need an id, I need to automatic generate the url.
What I did is creating a `XLink` component which take routeParams to generate the real url we need link to.

> For example, when we access C/00001/C1，we can get the routeParams: `{Id: "00001"}`，and then we click `<XLink to="C/:Id/C3">C3</XLink>` it will replace `:Id` with `"00001"`. Btw, XLink should support custom function to manually process the url.

**Seems like problem solved but it's not good enough. Any good ideas ?**

---

Since I came from an angular background, I think this case may be better solved by ui-router because it is based on "states", not url. The code may looks like this:

```html
/* Menus */
<Menu {...this.props}>
  ...
  <SubMenu state="C.detail">
    <Item state="C.detail.C1">
      <Link to="C.detail.C1">C1</Link>
    </Item>
    <Item state="C.detail.C2">
      <Link to="C.detail.C2">C2</Link>
    </Item>
    <Item state="C.detail.C3">
      <Link to="C.detail.C3">C3</Link>
    </Item>
  </SubMenu>
<Menu>
```

I don't have to process the route params，and I could use `state` for both highlight and linking.

**I'm quite new to react-router, if I made terrible mistakes, pls tell me.**

Comment: Why do you need ID in the path? Can't you just have `C/C1` etc?

Comment: We want our url readable, for example '/users/01/blogs' means user 01's blogs

Comment: Okay. Why do you need a component to update `:id` in Link as opposed to something like `to={'users/${id}/blogs'}`? (not sure how to escape backticks in comments!

Comment: Yes, that should be simpler. And the other issue is in react-router you have to write the complete url like {'something/users/${id}/blogs'}, it's better to use some kind of state instead of url.